# Prepared Statement do not return rows even the data is existed

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello how should I make this work:

I am wondering why when I'm using a prepared statement it doesn't work. I tried using the query method and it works.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$query = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'sample');

$rows = $query->query('SELECT * FROM `sample`.`sample_user` WHERE `userName` = "test" AND `userPass` = "data"');
echo $rows->num_rows; // this returns 1 since I have this record from my database
```

I'm trying to enhanced it by using a prepared statement :

```
$query = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'sample');
$prepared = $query->prepare('SELECT * FROM `sample`.`sample_user` WHERE `userName` = ? AND `userPass` = ?');

$prepared->bind_param("ss", $userName, $userPass );
$prepared->execute();
echo $prepared->num_rows; //this returns 0
```

I'm stuck with this issue. Maybe there's something I missed.

Comment: Consult the duplicate; there are a few things you didn't do/use.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner can you closed this thread.

Comment: what do you mean? I don't understand what you mean by *"can you closed this thread"*.

Comment: I  already solved the problem. Can I closed the question?

Comment: I already closed the question with a duplicate where it shows you how to do this correctly. You didn't store nor bound the results.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that, I thought it works without calling the get_result()

Comment: The manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php states => *"MySQL Native Driver Only... Available only with mysqlnd."*.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need to return the results, binding just bind the query to the params you provide.

```
 /* Get the result */
 $result = $stmt->get_result();

 /* Get the number of rows */
 $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
```